# Play Framework 1.x Functional Test with @AllowFeature Controller Method

Tags: java, playframework-1.x, junit3

I do want to write some functional tests for our project. Techstack: Play Framework 1.5, Java 16, Junit 3.

I found following documentation:
[test - 1.5.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.5.x/test)
[security - 1.5.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.5.x/security)

So the Controller looks something like this.

```
@AllowFeature(Feature.SEARCH_BOX)
public static void search(String term) {
    //implementation omitted

    TablePage<MyAwesomeType> page = search(term);

    render(..., page, term);
}
```

And my test looks like this

```
public class SearchTest extends FunctionalTest {

    @Test
    public void search_withResults() {
        String term = "ABC";
        Http.Response response = GET("/foo/search?term=" + term);

        assertStatus(302, response);

        assertThat(renderArgs("page"), is(notNullValue()));
        TablePage<MyAwesomeType> page = (TablePage<MyAwesomeType>) renderArgs("page");

        assertTrue(page.getTotalRecords() >= 1);
    }

}
```

However, the `TablePage<MyAwesomeType> page` is null when it really should not be, and i am unable to step into the controller method with the debugger. So it looks like the controller method `search(...)` is not called at all.

The response Code is `302 - Found` but I think this might be play suggestion it found the path `/foo/search`

My guess is that i need to setup some `UserContext` or send a `authenticityToken` along with the request. So play can check the required feature `@AllowFeature(Feature.A_SEARCH_BOX)`.

Does anybody know how I would setup such a functional test?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.

I need to log into the application and then the play `FunctionalTest.class` takes care of the cookie.

1. Add `@NoAuthenticity`to the login method

```
@NoAuthenticity // <-- This enables execution without authenticityToken
public static void login(@Required String username, @Required String password) {
    ... 
}
```

2. Post a request to login before the test.

```
@Test
public void search_withResults() {
    // 1. login
    Map<String, String> credentials = Map.of("username", "MyUsername", "password", "MyPassword");
    POST("/login", credentials); 
    // Note: session info / authenticityToken is stored in a cookie
    // FunctionalTest.class makes sure to use this cookie for subsequent requests

    // This request now works like a charm
    String term = "ABC";
    Http.Response response = GET("/foo/search?term=" + term);

    assertStatus(302, response);

    assertThat(renderArgs("page"), is(notNullValue()));
    TablePage<MyAwesomeType> page = (TablePage<MyAwesomeType>) renderArgs("page");

    assertTrue(page.getTotalRecords() >= 1);
}
```

Note: One can use the JUnit `@Before` Annotation to simplify the test class.

```
@Before
public void login(){
    Map<String, String> credentials = Map.of("username", "MyUsername", "password", "MyPassword");
    POST("/login", credentials);
}

@Test
public void search_withResults() {
    String term = "ABC";
    Http.Response response = GET("/foo/search?term=" + term);

    assertStatus(302, response);

    assertThat(renderArgs("page"), is(notNullValue()));
    TablePage<MyAwesomeType> page = (TablePage<MyAwesomeType>) renderArgs("page");

    assertTrue(page.getTotalRecords() >= 1);
}

@Test
public void anotherTest() { ... }

@Test
public void yetAnotherTest() { ... }
```